# Getting text content of seleted select element

Tags: jquery, html

As defined [here in documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/), I should get "Pay by Invoice" when I selected it and if I use `$("#paymentMethod:selected").text()` but for some reason it doesn't work for me. I bet I'm missing something simple. Anyone would know why my tests below won't work?

e.g. If I select "Pay by Invoice" and hit something (button, link etc), It should console.log "Pay by Invoice".

HTML:

```
<select id="paymentMethod" name="billingformtype[paymentMethod]">
        <option value="8">Pay by Credit or Debit Card</option>
        <option value="9">Pay by Invoice</option>
</select>

//Prints "Pay by Credit or Debit CardPay by Invoice" whatever I select
var selected = $("#paymentMethod").text();
console.log(selected.trim());

//Prints empty string whatever I select
var selected = $("#paymentMethod:selected").text();
console.log(selected.trim());
```

Comment: It has to be `$("#paymentMethod :selected").text();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:selected` selector applies to the `option` elements within the `select`, so you should use either:

```
$("#paymentMethod :selected").text() // note the space
```

or

```
$("#paymentMethod option:selected").text()
```

Comment: So it was all about missing space before :selected then! Thank you. +1. 10 minutes to accept it.

Comment: @inanzzz without space `:selected` (and all other selectors in general) was applied directly to `#paymentMethod`, while with space `:selected` is searched through `#paymentMethod` descendants.

Comment: I vonder who downvoted my upvote! I accepted it since it solves the problem and I don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `value=""` attribute from the `<select>` -> `<options>`,

```
<select id="paymentMethod">
    <option>Pay by Credit or Debit Card</option>
    <option>Pay by Invoice9</option>
    <option>etc.</option>
    <option>etc.</option>
</select>
```

then, you can simply do this:

```
//jQuery
$('#paymentMethod').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});

//or Javascript
paymentMethod.onchange = function(){
    alert(this.value);
};
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/oojku0L7/)**